# Cannot access class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar'

Tags: android, kotlin, anko, snackbar

I am getting the following error while I was trying to show the **snackbar**.

> Cannot access class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies.

And I have already added the anko library,anko-design library and support design library.

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.5'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.25.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Here the image of error that I am getting in the android studio.

[image: error for snackbar]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01' and delete the the two line above

Comment: I can't do that because I am using the Anko kotlin library to ease the development and also it's a great library for android development with kotlin.

Comment: see issue tracker for this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111195890

Answer (score 3):

update the following libraries:

1. `implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.8"`
2. `implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.8"`.

That should fix the issue.

Comment: it worked. thanks. I didn't use the latest version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your code, but you can alternatively achieve what you want with the following code snippet:

```
Snackbar.make(View, String, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: Ya, it should work but it's also not working showing the error unresolved reference make.

Comment: Did you implement the design support library?. Also, I don't think you need the Anko library if you're just trying to display snack bar.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and try change to
 `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` 
and work perfectly

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. But it didn't helped, it just produced some another error actually a lot of error with title _Resource linking failed_